# Prove that $x^2 + 3 > 2x + 1$ for all values of $x$

Tags: proof-verification

how would I go about proving this:

$x^2 + 3 > 2x + 1$

I know that I have to complete the square but do I bring everything to one side and convert it to an equation or do I simply complete the first side?
Sorry if this seems nooby

Comment: move everything to the left and then complete the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Adding to both sides $-2x-1$ it is equivalent to
$$
x^2-2x+2=(x-1)^2+1>0
$$

Answer (score 4):

$x^2+3>2x+1 \Leftrightarrow x^2-2x+1+1>0\Leftrightarrow (x-1)^2+1>0$

Which is true for every x.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer so you have to downvote it?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Take everything over to the left hand side and then complete there square.

Example: Show that $x^2 > 2x-6$ for all $x$:

$$x^2 > 2x - 6 \iff x^2 - 2x + 6 > 0 \iff (x-1)^2 +5 > 0$$
Since $(x-1)^2 \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, we have $(x-1)^2 + 5 \ge 5$.
Hence $(x-1)^2 + 5 > 0$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

*With Analysis:*

Just to show there isn't a single way to prove inequalities.

The tangent to the parabola with equation $y=x^2+3$ at point $A=(1,4)$ has equation 
$y=2(x-1)+4=2x+2$.

Now the function is convex, i.e. its graph is *above* each of  its tangents, so for all $x$,
$$x^2+3\ge 2x+2~(>2x+1).$$